# Piping from parent parent to child process not working

Tags: c, process, pipe, fork

For my assignment, I am required to make a menu with four options (add node, list nodes, remove node, and quit) and when the user selects one of these four options (with either 1, 2, 3, or 4, respectively), the child process handles the selection. I don't have options 2 or 3 implemented yet, so don't worry about those two. Here is my code so you can get an idea of the layout:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main()
{
    int p[2];
    char option[10];
    int node_num = 1;
    int rd, wr, tail = 0;

    pid_t first_fork;
    first_fork = fork();

    pipe(p);

    if (first_fork > 0)
    {
        // root
        do
        {
            printf("NODES MENU\n");
            printf("    1) ADD NODE\n");
            printf("    2) LIST NODES\n");
            printf("    3) REMOVE NODE\n");
            printf("    4) QUIT\n");
            printf("SELECT AN OPTION: ");

            fgets(option, 10, stdin);
            write(p[1], option, 1);

            if (option[0] != '1' && option[0] != '2' && option[0] != '3' && option[0] != '4')
            {
                printf("[Invalid Selection]\n");
            }
        } while (option[0] != '4');
    }
    else
    {
        // first node
        read(p[0], option, 1);

        if (option[0] == 1 && tail == 1)
        {
            int p2[2];
            node_num++;
            pipe(p2);
            pid_t cpid;
            cpid = fork();

            if (cpid > 0)
            {
                // parent
                tail = 0;
                wr = p2[1];
            }
            else
            {
                // child
                printf("[Node:  %d PID:     %d  HAS BEEN ADDED...]\n", node_num, getpid());
                tail = 1;
                rd = p2[0];
            }
        }
        if (option[0] == '2')
        {
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < node_num; i++)
            {
                printf("[Node: %d   PID: %d     PPID: %d    RD: %d  WR: %d\n", node_num, getpid(), getppid(), rd, wr);
            }
        }
        if (option[0] == '3')
        {
            printf("remove");
        }
    }
}
```

As of right now, my main concern is just getting the add option to work properly. After the `fgets` function to get the users option, the parent process should write to the first 'node' (child process) using `write()` and `read()`. Then, inside of the child process, the options should be handled accordingly (except for option 4, which gets handled by the do-while loop).

The menu works perfectly; the invalid selection portion works, as well as option 4 for quit. However, when I select option 1, nothing gets printed and the menu pops up again (like it's supposed to, until I select option 4). The same problem occurs with options 2 and 3.

Here is a same of the output:

```
NODES MENU
    1) ADD NODE
    2) LIST NODES
    3) REMOVE NODE
    4) QUIT
SELECT AN OPTION: 1
NODES MENU
    1) ADD NODE
    2) LIST NODES
    3) REMOVE NODE
    4) QUIT
SELECT AN OPTION: 4
```

The child process is not printing anything out like it's supposed to.

I tried changing the `else` for the first child to just another if statement of the form

```
if (first_fork == 0)
```

but nothing happens. In fact, I tried this same exact thing yesterday, and I was at least was able to print out that the node was added; but now nothing is printing and I have no idea what I changed for it to work before, but not now.

I tried using the `close()` function to send the data from the parent to the child by closing p[1] in the child (before the `read()`) and closing `p[0]` in the parent (before the `write()`). This doesn't do anything.

I thought maybe I need to use a `wait(NULL)` function call after I write to the child, but that stopped the menu from popping back up (perhaps I'm just using the `wait` function wrong?).

I tried getting rid of the `&& tail == 1` check; that also didn't do anything.

So my only guesses left are that it has something to do with the do-while loop, and/or the pipes not writing and reading properly, and/or the if-statements not reading the characters correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two biggest errors are:

- You forked before you created a pipe.

  That means that the parent and the child can not communicate because they have each their own pipe instead of having a shared pipe. You should create a pipe before forking.
- The child process is not looping.

  The child is only reading once from the pipe. It should be reading from the pipe in a loop until it gets a message from the parent to kill itself.

Comment: Yup, I was going to point out that `p` is not initialized before use.  The OP should enable all warnings.

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I've been looking at my code for 3 hours only to find out that these were the problems. Both of these errors make perfect sense. I've also added a check in the while loop to break out of it when read fails. Also, is there a way to enable all warnings in c9? That's the IDE I'm using for this class